# Xcode swift preview fails with 'Unknown preview provider "<classname>_"'

Tags: xcode, swiftui

There are a few similar questions here, but no answers resolve the issue for me.
My project doesn't start with a number.

It is essentially just this:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class DetailsView: UIView {

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setupBackgroud()
    setupViews()
  }

  func setupBackgroud() {}

  func setupViews() {}
}

#if DEBUG
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 13, *)
struct DetailsViewPreview: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    // view controller using programmatic UI
    DetailsView().showPreview()
  }
}

#endif
```

and I get the error:

[image]

I have *no* idea what the 'mangled name' is.

Comment: You need a `UIViewRepresentable` to convert UIKit to SwiftUI

Comment: Is it because your project name has numbers prefix? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65873684/swiftui-unknown-preview-provider-contentview-previews-when-previewing-happ

Answer (score 0):

The *stupidest* fix possible for this error.
I removed the compiler pre-proccessor statements.

Just remove `#if DEBUG` and `#endif`.

"It Just Works" ‍♂️